# Creating a userform with PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

There are lots of tutorials out there that show you how to create userforms in Python, but I can't find any which then show you how to retrieve whatever is entered into that form.

Here's an example I found where the userform looks perfect, but the buttons don't do anything:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
QVBoxLayout)

import sys

class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
#        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.getInfo)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout - pythonspot.com")

#    def getInfo(self):
#        shost = self.Name.text()
#        print(shost)

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Name"), QLineEdit())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Country"), QComboBox())
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Age"), QSpinBox())
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

The commented lines are lines that I added that don't work. Obviously `self.Name.text()` isn't the right syntax, but I can't figure out what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of things that you are missing in the code. 
e.g `buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)` accept button is connected to dummy accept. you need to connect this button to your `self.getInfo`,

**To answer why you are failing to retrieve values:**  you do not have object handles from your `QLineEdit, QComboBox, QSpinBox` which means you cannot access them later to read the updated text.

Following is the fixed code which will connect accept to `self.getInfo(self)` and upon pressing `OK` it will print the values in **Name, Country, Age** fields .

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDialog,
                             QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout,
                             QLabel, QLineEdit, QMenu, QMenuBar, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QTextEdit,
                             QVBoxLayout)

import sys


class Dialog(QDialog):
    NumGridRows = 3
    NumButtons = 4

    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.formGroupBox = QGroupBox("Form layout")
        self.ageSpinBar = QSpinBox()
        self.countryComboBox = QComboBox()
        self.countryComboBox.addItems(["Pakistan", "USA", "UAE"])
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.createFormGroupBox()

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.getInfo)
        #        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.getInfo)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.formGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Form Layout - pythonspot.com")

    def getInfo(self):
        print("Person Name : {0}".format(self.nameLineEdit.text()))
        print("Country : {0}".format(self.countryComboBox.currentText()))
        print("Age : {0}".format(self.ageSpinBar.text()))
        self.close()

    def createFormGroupBox(self):
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow(QLabel("Name"), self.nameLineEdit)
        layout.addRow( QLabel("Country"),self.countryComboBox)
        layout.addRow( QLabel("Age"), self.ageSpinBar)
        self.formGroupBox.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(dialog.exec_())
```

**Note : self.close()** will close the window if you don't want to close just comment this line out. 
Hope this helps :)